# How do i return the value of a integer from a class to my main? C#

Tags: c#, class, arguments

So i have trouble with returning the value from an integer, from a class.

So this is my main program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MatchGame
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //( Amount of matches, bot argument, player argument, gameover?,)

        //AI MatchGame = new AI(0, 0, 0, false, 0, false);

        int matchAmount = 0;
        int botMove = 0;
        int playerMove = 0;
        bool gameOver = false;
        int playerMoveAttempt = 0;
        bool choseRightAmount = false;


        void TurnPlayer()
        {

            PlayersTurn PlayerMoved = new PlayersTurn(); //choseRightAmount, playerMoveAttempt, playerMove, matchAmount);

            PlayersTurn.PlayerTurnMove(choseRightAmount, playerMoveAttempt, playerMove, matchAmount);




                Console.WriteLine(playerMoveAttempt);
                playerMove = playerMoveAttempt;
                matchAmount = matchAmount - playerMove;




        } 

       /*
        void PlayerTurn()
        {
            choseRightAmount = false;

            while (!choseRightAmount)
            {

                playerMoveAttempt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (playerMoveAttempt < 1 || playerMoveAttempt > 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please take between 1 and 3 matches");
                }
                else
                {
                    playerMove = playerMoveAttempt;
                    matchAmount = matchAmount - playerMove;
                    choseRightAmount = true;
                }

            }
        } */


        void BotTurn()
        {
            botMove = matchAmount % 4;
            matchAmount = matchAmount - botMove;
        }


        void Status()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bot took " + botMove + " matches from the board.");
            Console.WriteLine("There are " + matchAmount + " matches left.");
        }


        void Game()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the game!");
            Console.WriteLine("To win you need to take the last match!");
            Console.WriteLine("You can only take between  1 and 3 matches per turn.");
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose the amount of matches you want.");
            matchAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("You chose " + matchAmount + " It is your turn, please take between 1 and 3 matches");


            while (!gameOver)
            {

                TurnPlayer();

                if (matchAmount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Won.");
                    break;
                }

                BotTurn();
                if (matchAmount <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You lost! The bot won the match!");
                    gameOver = true;
                    break;
                }

                Status();

            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        Game();


    }
}
}
```

So i need to get the value of playerMove attempt from the class. I know i can easely do this inside the main program, but my teacher wants us to use classes. I need to use it in TurnPlayer() so i can calculate the amount of matches that are left. This is being used in the while loop in the buttom.

Here is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MatchGame
{
    public class PlayersTurn
{

    public static int PlayerTurnMove(bool choseRightAmount, int playerMoveAttempt, int playerMove, int matchAmount)
    {



        choseRightAmount = false;

        while (!choseRightAmount)
        {

            playerMoveAttempt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (playerMoveAttempt < 1 || playerMoveAttempt > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please take between 1 and 3 matches");
            }
            else
            {

                choseRightAmount = true;
                return playerMoveAttempt;


            }



        }

        return playerMoveAttempt;

    }

}
}
```

So yea, as you can see i am trying to return playerMoveAttempt. I already know the Class is working, it is just not returning the new values.

Hope some of you can help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your method call to the variable like this:

```
playerMoveAttempt = PlayersTurn.PlayerTurnMove(choseRightAmount, playerMoveAttempt, playerMove, matchAmount);
Console.WriteLine(playerMoveAttempt);
```

Bear in mind everything you do inside `PlayerTurnMove` method won't change the values of `playerMoveAttempt`, `playerMove` and `matchAmount` outside of it, although it's possible to accomplish this behavior. You should read about **variable scopes**.

Since your method is returning **only the value of `playerMoveAttempt`**, it's possible to assign this result of your method to a variable, like my code sample above.

---

I realize this is a homework and you're learning the basics, just wanted to point out you should consider learning about `static` classes/methods, when to use them and when not to use. Although my code sample above should work, a more elegant solution to your problem would be to use your class like this:

```
public class PlayersTurn
{

    public int PlayerMoveAttempt { get; set; }
    public int PlayerMove{ get; set; }
    public int MatchAmount{ get; set; }

    public PlayersTurn(int playerMoveAttempt, int playerMove, int matchAmount)
    {
        this.PlayerMoveAttempt = playerMoveAttempt;
        this.PlayerMove = playerMove;
        this.MatchAmount = matchAmount;
    }

    public void PlayerTurnMove()
    {
        while (this.playerMoveAttempt < 1 || this.playerMoveAttempt > 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please take between 1 and 3 matches");
            this.playerMoveAttempt = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }    
    }
}
```

...then change your method from the console application:

```
void TurnPlayer()
{
    PlayersTurn playerMoved = new PlayersTurn(playerMoveAttempt, playerMove, matchAmount);
    playerMoved.PlayerTurnMove();

    Console.WriteLine(playerMoved.PlayerMoveAttempt);
    playerMove = playerMoved.PlayerMoveAttempt;
    matchAmount = playerMoved.MatchAmount - playerMoved.PlayerMove;
}
```

Still not the best design, because using `Console.ReadLine()` inside a class is not generally a good idea, as this method is highly coupled with **Console Applications**, and it's working just because we are using this class inside it.

If you ever wanted to *reuse* this class and its logic in another type of aplication (e.g a Windows Form, an Web Application), this would not work properly. Your class **shouldn't be aware of the mechanism used to get an input** from the user.

I'd guess it's ok for now since you're just learning, maybe the next step of your teacher would be to refactor exactly this, but it'd be nice if you started trying to understand these concepts.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alisson! It worked! And thanks for the tips!

Comment: @SubFeedSub thanks for your feedback, I'm glad it could help you.